# is there a firefox-like plugin container for chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash

I just switched to chrome some days ago and I am very happy with it, but there was one thing with Firefox I really liked: The plugin container. From time to time the flash player hangs up and with Firefox I was very happy that I just had to kill the plugin container, reload the page and everything was fine again.

Now, with chrome, the browser itself hangs up, so I have to restart chrome - and with this all of my 5 windows and 40 tabs.

So, is there an extension for chrome, that adds a new layer between the browser and the flash player, so that I only have to kill the flash player itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome is multi-process as well. If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> you can open Chrome's task manager and kill an unresponsive Flash instance or tab without bringing down the whole browser.

Comment: Hey! Great! Thanks for this hint! For me it's just Shift+ESC. That's even better than the Firefox's plugin container - or does Firefox also have such a built-in task manager?

Comment: On my Win 7 machine - Shift-ESC brings up Chrome's Task Manager and Ctrl-Shift-ESC brings up the Windows ask Manager.

Comment: Sorry I had these wrong, it is in fact just shift-esc. Chrome is completely multi process, and spins off each individual tab and plugin into a separate chrome.exe, killing these when the tab is closed to prevent memory leaks. To my knowledge, Firefox simply keeps plugins out of process and hasn't moved to a fully multi-process architecture yet.

Details on Chrome's implementation can be found [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html)

Comment: @TedO'Hayer Fixed! ;)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks. Chrome keeps surprising me with things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Session Box have similar functionality to Firefox Containers
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-multi-login-to/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig